# A case when a user-provided explicitly-defaulted function defined as deleted

Tags: c++

There is the following quote from `N3797::8.4.2/4 [dcl.fct.def.default]`:

> A function is user-provided if it is user-declared and not explicitly
>   defaulted or deleted on its first declaration. A user-provided
>   explicitly-defaulted function (i.e., explicitly defaulted after its
>   first declaration) is defined at the point where it is explicitly
>   defaulted; *if such a function is implicitly defined as deleted, the*
>   *program is ill-formed.*

I tried to invent an example reflecting that rule. Since, the Standard says:

> If the class definition does not explicitly declare a copy
>   constructor, one is declared implicitly. If the class definition
>   declares a move constructor or move assignment operator, *the*
>   *implicitly declared copy constructor is defined as deleted*;

the following code should throw an error about deleted function call:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct A
{ 
    A(){ }
    A(const A&&){ cout << "A(const&&)" << endl; }
    A(const A&) = default;
};

A a;

A b = a;

int main() {
}
```

But it works fine. Can you provide an actual example reflecting this?

**[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2ae86f3f26d5d842)**

Comment: I think you are confusing the terms *implicit* and *user-provided*, if you declare a function, by definition it is not *implicit*. A special function can be optionally `default`ed on its first declaration, in which case it is not *user-provided*, but that doesn't make it *implicit*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My other answer was incorrect. In your case, `A`'s copy-constructor isn't user-provided since it is explicitly-defaulted on its first declaration. A user-provided explicitly-defaulted function would look like this:

```c++
struct X
{
    X();
};

X::X() = default;
```

The clause is pertaining to when the constructor is implicitly-deleted at the point where it's defaulted. Take this example:

```c++
struct X
{
    X(X&&); // user-declared move-constructor, deletes X's copy-constructor
};

struct Y
{
    X x; // data member with deleted copy-constructor deletes Y's
         // copy-constructor
    Y(Y const&);
};

// program is ill-formed. Y's copy-constructor was implicitly deleted
Y::Y(Y const&) = default;
```

Since `X` has an implicitly-deleted copy-constructor it follows that `Y` has an implicitly-deleted copy-constructor by virtue of `x` being its data member. Explicitly defaulting the constructor after its declaration is ill-formed.

Comment: That's a bit silly and inconsistent. Removing the inheritance and doing `Derived(Derived&&) { }` instead doesn't result in such errors. Strikes me as odd.

Comment: @Rapptz I'm sure there's a quote that pertains to that situation (where the user-provided move-ctor doesn't delete an explicitly defaulted copy-ctor in the same class). I think this example applies to the OP's quote.

Comment: Indeed, thank you. All these cases covered by 12.8/11.

Answer (score 4):

The following example explains it:

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {} 
    const int m_a;
};
```

Since m_a is a const member, the compiler implicitly deletes the copy assignment operator function `A& operator=(const A&)`. So you cant't do the following

```
int main() {
    A var1(1);
    A var2(3);
    var2 = var1;
}
```

You should get a compile time error like `copy assignment operator implicitly deleted`. Now you'll be tempted to explicitly default it

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {} 
    A& operator=(const A& other) = default;

    const int m_a;
};
```

You'll still get a compile time error and may see a message like `explicitly defaulted function was implicitly deleted`. But if you absolutely need the assignment operator say to copy the other non-const members you can explicitly define it as below.

```
class A {
public:
    A(int a) : m_a(a) {} 
    A& operator=(const A& other) {
    m_b = other.m_b;
    }

const int m_a;
int m_b = 0;
};
```

I think the reason behind this is obvious. We can't re-assign const variables(and non copyable members) after they have been initialized during construction. Although one may argue that a default behavior should be allowed that only copies non-const(and copyable) members. But to people who aren't aware of this behavior, might be under a false impression that the const members(and non-copyable) are also getting re-assigned causing all sorts of bugs.